In Singleton lateinit property packageInfoData has not been initialized
I am an Android Developer.
I want to use Singelton with dagger hilt 2, I am using Jetpack Compose.
This is my code right now:
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class PackagesDataSingleton @Inject constructor() {

    private lateinit var packageInfoData: PackageInfoData
    fun setPackageInfoData(packageInfoData: PackageInfoData) {
        this.packageInfoData = packageInfoData
    }

    fun getPackageInfoData(): PackageInfoData {
        return packageInfoData
    }
}

This is how I am using setPackageInfoData:
@HiltViewModel
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getPackagesSim: GetPackagesSim,
    private val packagesDataSingleton: PackagesDataSingleton,
) : BaseViewModel() {
    private fun getPackagesSimApi() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            getPackagesSim().collect { result ->
                when (result) {
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        result.data?.let {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                packagesDataSingleton.setPackageInfoData(it)
                            }
...

And in production, I get this crash from crashlytics:
Fatal Exception: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException
lateinit property packageInfoData has not been initialized
com.pelephone.peleglobal.manager.PackagesDataSingleton.getPackageInfoData (PackagesDataSingleton.kt:16)

I know for sure that all users execute the code setPackageInfoData, and if not they didn't use the getPackageInfoData.
And also I can't reproduce this crash on my side.
What can lead to this crash, do you have any idea?

Hey just update the code where you getPackageInfoData  calling this on your code

@SanthoshKumar
There is more than 1 place that I call getPackageInfoData, do you think this is important?

I would add log statements on all places where getPackageInfoData is being called to check if it is being called before it is being initialized. Perhaps there are places where the order of calling is different that you expected it to be.
